# How do I show only top level JSON entries that are not arrays or objects with jq version 1.3?

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON structure and I only want to print the entries that are simple types, e.g. not arrays or objects.

Sample input:

```
{
  "person": {
    "address": {
      "city": "NY",
      "street": "Wall Street"
    },
    "god": true,
    "nicks": [
      "Lar",
      "L",
      "Yo"
    ],
    "name": "Larry",
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

Expected output:

```
"god": true,
"name": "Larry",
"id": 1
```

I tried many different variations on this which did not work:

`jq '.person | with_entries(.) | select(map(type) != "array" and map(type) != "object")'`

Please note that I am on jq version 1.3.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not really doing anything with the `with_entries` call there. But you probably should be filtering there. Filter the entries where the value's type is neither an array nor an object.

```
.person | with_entries(select(.value | type | . != "array" and . != "object"))
```

If you were on a more recent version of jq, you could filter using the `scalars` builtin which effectively does the same thing.

```
.person | with_entries(select(.value | scalars))
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @jeff-mercado, that worked like a charm.  I am going to try to get my sysadmin to upgrade jq, 1.3 is pretty old I know :)